# How to access nested key from dictionary using ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I need to access `lat` and `lng`. How can I do that?

[image]

This is what I do now, and it doesn't work:

```
latitude <- map["location"]["lat"]
longitude <- map["location"]["lng"]
```

Comment: Why you don't use the new Codable protocol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just simply need:

```
latitude <- map["location.lat"]
longitude <- map["location.lng"]
```

So far [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#easy-mapping-of-nested-objects) supports dot notation within keys for easy mapping of nested objects (you could find it under "Easy Mapping of Nested Objects" in library documentation).

Answer (score 2):

You would need to declare a separated class for the location to contain the `lat` and the `lng` properties:

```
class Location: Mappable {
    var lat: Double?
    var lng: Double?

    required init?(map: Map){ }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        lat <- map["lat"]
        lng <- map["lng"]
    }
}
```

thus you could use it as:

```
class Base: Mappable {
    var location: Location?
    // ...

    required init?(map: Map){ }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        location <- map["location"]
        //...
    }
}
```

It would represent a nested type for mapping the base object.

---

*Aside bar note:* you might also want to check [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) - [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: Are you sure that [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49556381/5501940) worked? :D

Comment: The same question about first element in array of elements. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have found an answer: ‚.0’

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ObjectMapper , you can use [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) , that will enable you to write only the key of the objects inside the json  , instead of writing them twice with ObjectMapper. (as a property and inside map function ) , especially if the server keys naming is suitable for you

Comment: Yes, you are right, but very often I need to change their naming;) But your answer is very helpful...

Answer (score -3):

Hope this helps you

```
 let data = NSData(contentsOf: searchUrl as URL)
                let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                let status = json["status"] as! String
                print(status)
                if status == "OK" {
                    if let result = json["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                        if let geometry = result[0]["geometry"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                            if let location = geometry["location"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                                lat = location["lat"] as! Double
                                lng = location["lng"] as! Double
                                print(lat)
                                print(lng)
                            }
                      }
                 }
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with using `JSONSerialization`. Even so, your answer doesn't provide a correct result.

Comment: but am using this concept in my project

Comment: anyways it's not helping you!.But definitely it's help some developers